# Rails query find result with partiular day with where cluase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, zone

I want to orders which are confirmed particular day.

This is particular day:

```
today = Time.zone.now

Wed, 10 Jun 2015 13:31:16 IST +05:30
```

This is range of particular day

```
value = today.beginning_of_day()..today.end_of_day()
Wed, 10 Jun 2015 00:00:00 IST +05:30..Wed, 10 Jun 2015 23:59:59 IST +05:30
```

But when I execute this, SQL query date range is changed,

```
orders = Order.where(confirmed_at: value)

SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."confirmed_at" BETWEEN '2015-06-09 18:30:00.000000' AND '2015-06-10 18:29:59.999999' ORDER BY orders.confirmed_at DESC
```

In this orders confiremed between '2015-06-09 18:30:00.000000' AND '2015-06-10 18:29:59.999999'

But I wants confirmed between 'Wed, 10 Jun 2015 00:00:00 IST +05:30..Wed, 10 Jun 2015 23:59:59 IST +05:30'

Comment: do you want to compare date or datetime?

Comment: I want to compare with datetime.

Comment: `value = today.to_time.beginning_of_day()..today.to_time.end_of_day()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Time.zone.now.to_time for today.

today = Time.zone.now.to_time

value = today.beginning_of_day()..today.end_of_day()

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Which DB are you using?

`ActiveRecord` will declare time columns using data types that do not support timezones. For example, in Postgres it will use [`timestamp without time zone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html).

This means that all `Time`, `DateTime` and `TimeWithZone` values set on an ActiveRecord object will be written to the DB as `UTC`.
Rails will then take care to apply and remove the right offsets each time the values are read or written, using the current value of `Time.zone` (e.g. for the current web request).

Just check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) for `TimeWithZone` and think about what should go in your `WHERE` clause.
It probably depends on the specific context, but you might have to use UTC values in your query.

Comment: Thanks, I am using PG.